# Como saber si un iframe esta cargado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un iframe estoy usando on load de jquery para saber si esta cargado de esta forma:

```
    let iframe = $(`.map iframe`);
    iframe.on('load', function(){
       stopAnimation()        
    })
```

quiero saber si de alguna forma es posible saber si ya se cargo el contenido del iframe. porque aveces se queda girando mi animacion y supongo que cuando recargo la pagina no vuelve a cargar el iframe, porque ya esta cargado. pero no se como detectar si lo esta.

intente esto pero no funciono:

```
iframe.on("readystatechange",function() { 
        if (this.readyState == "complete" || this.readyState == "interactive")
         { 
            loader.css("display","none"); 
            iframe.fadeIn(1000);
         } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que haya muchas maneras más fácil, pero yo comparto una forma entre tantas, que te puede ser de ayuda.

En la etiqueta `iframe` puedes agregar el evento `onlod()` de ésta forma:

```
<iframe onload="cargado();"></iframe>
```

Luego con la función `cargado` se crea la función que se decea:

```
function cargado() {

 // Función

}
```

Comment: De hecho eso es similar al codigo que deje arriba.  el problema es que no funciona onload cuando el iframe se representa desde el cache.